# How do you hyperlink to Word 2007 help pages?

Tags: vba, ms-office, office-2007, ms-word

I want to hyperlink to a page within the Word 2007 Object Model Reference documentation, that ships with Word 2007. These are webpages that use the `ms-help://` protocol that Firefox cannot understand.

So I wanted to specify the `ms-help://` path of the help page as a command line argument to the viewer, CLVIEW.EXE.

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\CLVIEW.EXE

Does anybody know the command line syntax for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CLVIEW.EXE doesn't support command line parameters to launch to a certain page. It's usually used to launch your own custom help file within the hosted Office application.

With Word 2007 there are some options available. They depend, let me repeat, they depend on whether your help is in online or offline mode.

1. If your intent is simply to get
   people to a specific Word help page
   *and* they have internet access, you can grab the URL from the help file
   in ***online*** mode. To do this,
   just right-click on the page you
   want the link, for example the
   *Make the text bold* page, to and click Properties. Then copy the URL
   (Address) which is:
   http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetID=HA100215341033&ns=WINWORD&lcid=1033. This will work just fine in FF (if you were in Offline mode, this
   same link would have been:
   *ms-help://MS.WINWORD.12.1033/WINWORD/content/HA10021534.htm*.)
2. If you are first sending them to
   Word, you can run an macro that
   brings up this topic. You grab the
   "Topic ID" from right-clicking on
   the page *Make the text bold* page
   (which, in this case is
   "HA10021534") and put that ID as the
   first parameter, like the below.
   **NOTE**: This should work in ***both
   online and offline mode***.

   ```
   Sub DisplayHelpTopic()   
       Application.Assistance.ShowHelp "HA10021534", ""
   End Sub
   ```
3. For developer documentation with the
   solution for #2, if you are in
   offline mode, you need to set the
   scope to "DEV" (which will also work
   if you are in online mode). So for
   the subject *Bibliography Object*,
   the Topic ID is: HV10096617. If you
   are in online mode, you don't need
   the "DEV" scope. Code:

   ```
   Sub DisplayHelpTopic()
      Application.Assistance.ShowHelp "HV10096617", "DEV"
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Very good, but the VBA code only works for help topics within the user set of docs, and **does not** work for developer documentation. Do I have to supply the Scope argument?

Comment: The scope for the developer documentation is "DEV". You only need that scope when your documentation is set to "offline". When set to online, you don't need it the scope. I've updated the above.

Comment: **+550** - Fantastic answer, Otaku! and thank you very much for answering this question and solving what was going to be quite an insurmountable task. Congrats on winning the 500 reputation points bounty! (the system added 50 to sweeten the deal)

Answer (score 2):

You *can* view these documentation pages in Internet Explorer.

1. Open up your Word docs to the page you want.
2. Right click, Properties and copy the ms-help:// URL.
3. Paste this URL in IE, it should open up fine.
4. Use the command line syntax for IE to hyperlink to it.

Hope that helps, although clicking links in IE may not work properly.
Maybe CLVIEW.EXE has command line syntax that can do this directly.